# AVAssetDownloadURLSession freeze when allocating and initialising

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avkit

I got problem with `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`. My app is downloading HLS videos and concurrently playing it. Everything works fine, except that after a while app freeze. It appears that

`init(configuration:assetDownloadDelegate:delegateQueue:)`

to be precise:
`AVAssetDownloadURLSession.__allocating_init(configuration:assetDownloadDelegate:delegateQueue:)`

never returns session object. It happens only on iOS 14.0 and iOS 14.1 (Didn't get it on iOS 14.2 till now). It could be only solved by restarting device. Instruments shows that main thread is blocked by:

```
   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg_trap
   1 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg
   2 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_mach_msg_send
   3 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_mach_send_drain
   4 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_mach_send_msg
   5 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply
   6 libdispatch.dylib dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply
   7 libxpc.dylib xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync
   8 Foundation __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__
   9 Foundation -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]
  10 CoreFoundation ___forwarding___
  11 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0
```

In the same time I'm checking OS console logs, but I don't know how to interpret it properly.

Maybe somebody has an idea or similar problem that was solved. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find the culprit in the end ? We have exactly the same issue for users on iOS 14.0 and 14.1. Only the device restart solves the issue.

Comment: I didn't found any culprit or other solution. I wrote to Apple Engineers, but they also didn't help me with it.

Comment: That's a bummer, thank you for taking the time to answer.